# 3D BoundaryMeshRegion Minkowski difference via RegionErosion Failure

Tags: finite-element-method, regions, mesh, computational-geometry

I need to be able to produce Minkowski difference of an arbitrary BoundaryMeshRegion and a cylinder.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
c1 = BoundaryMeshRegion[ToBoundaryMesh[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -5}, {0, 0, 5}}, 5]]];
c2 = BoundaryMeshRegion[ToBoundaryMesh[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]]];
RegionErosion[c1, c2]
```

It produces nothing:

[image]

However,

```
RegionErosion[Cylinder[{{0, 0, -5}, {0, 0, 5}}, 5], Cylinder[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]]
```

does work:

[image]

**So, is there any way to apply erosion to a mesh, or it's just not possible with current RegionErosion implementation?**

Comment: A shot in the blue: try to use a ToElementMesh with mesh order 1 and convert that to a mesh region.

Comment: @user21 naahh, no go either.

Comment: I think this is not implemented for discretized regions.